# Oracle - Unknown identifier when refering to subquery alias

Tags: oracle, subquery, alias

I have the following query:

```
select "Title_ID","Text",
(SELECT LISTAGG("Genre",',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Genre") from (SELECT DISTINCT "g"."Genre" from "RegionBroadcasts" left join "Genres" "g" on "RegionBroadcasts"."Genre" = "g".PK_GENRE where "RegionBroadcasts"."Region"=24 and "RegionBroadcasts"."Title_ID"="IDs"."Title_ID")) as "SourceGenres",
(SELECT LISTAGG("Genre",',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Genre") from (SELECT DISTINCT "g"."Genre" from "RegionBroadcasts" left join "Genres" "g" on "RegionBroadcasts"."Genre" = "g".PK_GENRE where "RegionBroadcasts"."Region"=1 and "RegionBroadcasts"."Title_ID"="IDs"."Title_ID")) as "TargetGenres",
(SELECT LISTAGG("Channel_Name",',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Channel_Name") from (SELECT DISTINCT "Channel_Name" from "ProgrammeChannels" left join "ChannelNames" on "ProgrammeChannels"."Channel"="ChannelNames"."Channel_ID" where "ProgrammeChannels"."Region"=24 and "ProgrammeChannels"."Title_ID"="IDs"."Title_ID")) as "SourceChannels",
(SELECT LISTAGG("Channel_Name",',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Channel_Name") from (SELECT DISTINCT "Channel_Name" from "ProgrammeChannels" left join "ChannelNames" on "ProgrammeChannels"."Channel"="ChannelNames"."Channel_ID" where "ProgrammeChannels"."Region"=1 and "ProgrammeChannels"."Title_ID"="IDs"."Title_ID")) as "TargetChannels"

from
((
select "LocalTitle" as "Title_ID" from "RegionBroadcasts2" where "Region" = 24
union
select "GlobalTitle" as "Title_ID" from "RegionBroadcasts2" where "Region" = 24)
intersect
(select "LocalTitle" as "Title_ID" from "RegionBroadcasts2" where "Region" = 1
union
select "GlobalTitle" as "Title_ID" from "RegionBroadcasts2" where "Region" = 1
)) "IDs"

left join "ProgrammeTitles" on "IDs"."Title_ID" = "ProgrammeTitles"."Text_ID"
where "IDs"."Title_ID" <> 1
and "IDs"."Title_ID" is not null
order by "Text";
```

For some reason, I have an exception of type "invalid identifier" in the 4 first "select listagg" statements where I'm linking "RegionBroadcasts"."Title_ID" with **"IDs"."Title_ID"**

Just as if I was not authorized to use the subquery "IDs".

I want to precise that if I'm replacing the "IDs"."Title_ID" by a fixed integer value, I will have some results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't allow to use parent columns in the subqueries, which are more than 1 level deep.

The simpliest way to fix that is to move `where` one level upper:

```
(SELECT LISTAGG("Genre",',') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Genre") 
 from (SELECT DISTINCT "g"."Genre", "RegionBroadcasts"."Title_ID" tmp_title_id 
       from "RegionBroadcasts" left join "Genres" "g" on "RegionBroadcasts"."Genre" = "g".PK_GENRE where "RegionBroadcasts"."Region"=24
      ) 
 where tmp_title_id = "IDs"."Title_ID") as "SourceGenres"
```

It may have a negative impact on performance, but I'm not sure if it's important here.